# Disconnected DataSet

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, datacontext

I am looking for architecture like as follows:

Database --> DataSet --> DataContext(Linq)/ ORM Entity --> GUI Application

I want to fetch data from database and keep into DataSet so if database id disconnect my

application doesn't affect.

But DataSet is not supporting Object-Relational-Mapping (ORM) Model. I am interested in

ORM because I want to take the advantages of LINQ.

and finally on My GUI i want to access Entity Classes.

Please Explain this by taking example like

1. College (Database Table)
    College_id   (Primary Key)
    College_name
2. Student (Database Table)
    Student_id  (Primary Key)
    Student_name 
    College_id  (Foreign Key)
    Student_mark

Design a GUI in One Drop Down List which contains College List and on College Selection

it displays Student List (Student Id,name,mark) in GridView.

Client Code i need something like this...

College cl = (College) DropDownList1.SelectedItem;
List student_list = cl.students;
GridView1.DataSource = student_list;
GridView.DataBind();

Thanks

Comment: Data Adapter serves the purpose of disconnected dataset . Thanks

Comment: Before I'd go down this road, I'd want to make sure that my application couldn't tolerate any downtime.  The complexity of the solution will decrease dramatically if you simply build the app to connect to the database and shut it down when the database isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach to that problem would be to use a local database such as SQL Server Compact, which you can synchronize with the main DB...

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use LINQ on DataSets.
Just make sure you have targeted .NET 3.5 and add "System.Data.DataSetExtensions" to your list of references.

Quote from MSDN:

> To target the .NET Framework 3.5 In
>   Visual Studio 2008, create a new
>   Visual Basic or C# project.
>   Alternatively, you can open a Visual
>   Basic or C# project that was created
>   in Visual Studio 2005 and follow the
>   prompts to convert it to a Visual
>   Studio 2008 project.
>
> For a C# project, click the Project
>   menu, and then click Properties.
>
> In the Application property page,
>   select .NET Framework 3.5 in the
>   Target Framework drop-down list.
>
> For a Visual Basic project, click the
>   Project menu, and then click
>   Properties.
>
> In the Compile property page, click
>   Advanced Compile Options and then
>   select .NET Framework 3.5 in the
>   Target Framework (all configurations)
>   drop-down list.
>
> On the Project menu, click Add
>   Reference, click the .NET tab, scroll
>   down to System.Core, click it, and
>   then click OK.
>
> Add a using directive or imported
>   namespace for System.Linq to your
>   source code file or project.
>
> For more information, see using
>   Directive (C# Reference) or How to:
>   Add or Remove Imported Namespaces
>   (Visual Basic).
>
> To enable LINQ to DataSet
>   functionality If necessary, follow the
>   steps earlier in this topic to add a
>   reference to System.Core.dll and a
>   using directive or imported namespace
>   for System.Linq.
>
> In C# or Visual Basic, click the
>   Project menu, and then click Add
>   Reference.
>
> In the Add Reference dialog box, click
>   the .NET tab if it is not on top.
>   Scroll down to System.Data and
>   System.Data.DataSetExtensions and
>   click on them. Click the OK button.
>
> Add a using directive or imported
>   namespace for System.Data to your
>   source code file or project. For more
>   information, see using Directive (C#
>   Reference) or How to: Add or Remove
>   Imported Namespaces (Visual Basic).
>
> Add a reference to
>   System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll for
>   LINQ to Dataset functionality. Add a
>   reference to System.Data.dll if it
>   does not already exist.
>
> Optionally, add a using directive or
>   imported namespace for
>   System.Data.Common or
>   System.Data.SqlClient, depending on
>   how you connect to the database.